# I have one issue like ringing siren in my application?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-mediaplayer

I am created one receiver in that if any thing wrong(like lock-screen password number of attempts is greater than 5)then i am ringing siren and i want to stop the siren in my activity, i am created that media player as a static value and i am accessing in my activity but it is not stoping what can i do.

Here is my receiver code to ring siren

```
public static MediaPlayer player, next;
player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.siren);
player.start();
player.setLooping(true);
```

and in my activity i have written like this:

```
if (MyReceiver.player != null) {
            if ((MyReceiver.player.isPlaying())) {
                MyReceiver.player.stop();
                MyReceiver.player.release();
                System.out.println("Player is recognized in mainActivity");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been solved this issue by using one separate class in that i have written startRinging(context) and stopRinging(),and i am calling startRinging from my Receiver and stopRinging from my Activity class then it is working properly.